# Run multiple recursive functions in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to do the "boggle" game, I have a 2D matrix with letters and I have to find words. 
Matrix: contains this letters: { {'C','A','R','T'}, {'E', 'T', 'A', 'K'}, {'E','S','M','E'}, {'L', 'L', 'P', 'N'} };
input: this matrix
output: all the words that found in matrix, from dictionary "isWord".

the code should take the matrix, index, index, word, and bool matrix.
every letter that I go on should marked in bool matrix as true, and then I continue with recursion untill its going out lengths. I go on 4 paths every time. I can't go back only forward.
the main problem with code that is running only in one path and not continuing with the rests of paths. [calling to "checkword" few times and it seems like its stick the first command].

Anyone ideas? pretty new in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <stdbool.h>
        bool isWord(char *s);

        void check(char mat[4][4]) {
            int i,j;
            int counter=0;
            for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
                for(j =0; j<4; j++) {
                    char str[12] = "";
                    //append(str, mat[i][j]);
                    bool checker[4][4]={{false}};
                    //printf("mat[%d][%d]: %s\n", i, j, str);
                    checkword(mat,i,j, str, checker);
                    counter++;
                     fflush(stdout);
                }
            }
        }
        void append(char* s, char c)
        {
                int len = strlen(s);
                s[len] = c;
                s[len+1] = '\0';
        }
        void checkword(char mat[4][4], int i, int j, char word[], bool checker[4][4]) 
        {
          if(i >= 0 && i<4 && j >= 0 && j < 4) 
          {
              if(!checker[i][j])
              {
                 // Mark current cell as visited and append current character
            // to str
            checker[i][j] = true;
            append(word, mat[i][j]);
            printf("%s\n", word);
            // If str is present in dictionary, then print it
            if (isWord(word))
                printf("Found word: %s\n", word);

            checkword(mat, i+1, j, word, checker); 
            checkword(mat, i, j+1, word, checker);
            checkword(mat, i, j-1, word, checker);
            checkword(mat, i-1, j, word, checker);
              }

         }
        }

        bool isWord(char* s) {
                return (!strcmp(s,"CAT") |
                    !strcmp(s,"CATS") |
                    !strcmp(s,"TRAM") |
                    !strcmp(s,"TRAMS") |
                    !strcmp(s,"TAME") |
                    !strcmp(s,"CAR") |
                    !strcmp(s,"CARS") |
                    !strcmp(s,"RAT") |
                    !strcmp(s,"RATS") |
                    !strcmp(s,"RAMP") |
                    !strcmp(s,"ART") |
                    !strcmp(s,"CART") |
                    !strcmp(s,"STAMP") |
                    !strcmp(s,"TAKEN") |
                    !strcmp(s,"MEN") |
                    !strcmp(s,"MAKE") |
                    !strcmp(s,"TAKE") |
                    !strcmp(s,"ATE") |
                    !strcmp(s,"SELL") |
                    !strcmp(s,"STEEL") |
                    !strcmp(s,"RAKE") );
        }



        int main() {
            char mat[4][4] = { {'C','A','R','T'}, {'E', 'T', 'A', 'K'}, {'E','S','M','E'}, {'L', 'L', 'P', 'N'} };
            check(mat);
         //   printf("Numbers of cells : %d", count);
        }
```

Comment: give sample input, output and expected output, and give a small explanation to your code as well, like what part of code doing what ( only main parts )

Comment: Matrix: contains this letters: { {'C','A','R','T'}, {'E', 'T', 'A', 'K'}, {'E','S','M','E'}, {'L', 'L', 'P', 'N'} };
input: this matrix
output: all the words that found in matrix, from dictionary "isWord".

the code should take the matrix, index, index, word, and bool matrix.
every letter that I go on should marked in bool matrix as true, and then I continue with recursion untill its going out lengths. I go on 4 paths every time.

Comment: you have to reset to false at the end of your checkword 'checker[i][j]=false;', otherwise it will just go one path through the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets go through what will happen if it runs:

for every starting point you do the same. e.g. (0,0)

1. checkword(mat, 1, 0, word, checker); -> (0,0) -> marked as checked
2. checkword(mat, 2, 0, word, checker); -> (1,0) -> marked as checked
3. checkword(mat, 3, 0, word, checker); -> (2,0) -> marked as checked
4. checkword(mat, 4, 0, word, checker); -> illegal
5. checkword(mat, 3, 1, word, checker); -> (3,0) -> marked as checked

this means you are only going through one path per starting point and checking for legal words.

What you want to do is go down every path from the starting point. you achieve this by unmarking the field as checked when you are finished going down all paths of recursion.

So add :

```
checkword(mat, i+1, j, word, checker); 
checkword(mat, i, j+1, word, checker);
checkword(mat, i, j-1, word, checker);
checkword(mat, i-1, j, word, checker);
checker[i][j]=false; // <-- clear path for other paths
shortenByOne(word);
```

edit:
also you will need to shorten the word once you're done- I forgot about that:

```
void shortenByOne(char* s)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        if(len==0) return;
        s[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: If I add it, it runs infinite loop.

Comment: @Avivzx yes, the problem was I didn't shorten the word again, but setting checker back to false is still essential. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about that, looks now better.